# Extending Lightning Components not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

My goal initially was to avoid pasting my common functions into every new components helper.js file [(previously researched)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228531/ltng-require-scripts-not-working-for-me) and I found out that you can extend the components [(some example codes)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170116/extending-lightning-components) I tried making a very simple base/abstract component and extending it like so:

1.Abstract component:

```
<aura:component extensible="true">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <!--<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.loaderStart}"/>-->
    <!--<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.loaderStop}"/>-->
    <p>This is inside abstract</p>
</aura:component>
```

abstract controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('doInit', component, event, helper);
    }
    /*
    loaderStart: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('loaderStart');
    },
    loaderStop: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('loaderStop');
    }
    */
})
```

abstract helper (just a bunch of simple stuff)

```
({
    closeQuickAction: function () {
        $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
    },
    refreshView: function () {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    },
    navigateToRecord: function (recordId) {
        // 'slideDevName': ( 'chatter', 'related', 'detail' )
        $A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject').setParams({'recordId': recordId, 'slideDevName': 'related'}).fire();
    }
})
```

2.And the component that extends it:

```
<aura:component extends="c:CmpBase" implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <p>This is inside extender</p>
    <lightning:button type="button" label="Test"/>
</aura:component>
```

This components (2) content does not show. Why?

Edit: contents and the console.log of the abstract component do show!

Found the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_cmp_attributes.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the abstract component you need to place the body:

```
<p>This is inside abstract</p>
{!v.body}
```

which is where the extending component's content is placed.

(When I had this problem I didn't manage to find an explicit explanation, just that examples had the `{!v.body}` in the abstract component.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that I have firsthand experience delving into the markup inheritance hierarchy, but I think the way it's explained under [Inherited Body Attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_cmp_attributes.htm) makes some sense of it - it being this requirement to include `{! v.body }` within the component markup of an abstract base component.

> The inheritance behavior of `body` is different than other attributes. It can have different values at each level of component extension to enable different output from each component in the inheritance chain...
>
> The default renderer for a component iterates through its body attribute, renders everything, and passes the rendered data to its super component. The super component can output the data passed to it by including `{!v.body}` in its markup. If there is no super component, you've hit the root component and the data is inserted into `document.body`.

There's also a concrete example provided.

This is sensical upon reflection (I think): if the inheritance hierarchy in the body weren't inverted in this fashion (super enclosing sub, rather than sub building on super), there wouldn't be a clear place for markup from the subcomponent to slot in.